# Dynamic Spreadsheet using HTML + JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got a couple of questions.  I'm attempting to create a dynamic spreadsheet, with the capabilities of having values inserted into it as well as (and only needed) being able to process the SUM() formula.  The problem I've run into right now, is when inserting a value. 
 Firstly allow em to show the JS I have for the insertion. The HTML table is using id values of 1_1,1_2 etc.

EDIT: Fixed the var column= document.getElementById(insert); line, however it doesn't seem to want to commit any inserted value. Shouldn't it simply be a return statement to commit a change to the html field?

```
function insertValue() {
    var v = document.getElementById("submitText");
    v = v.value;
    var row = document.getElementById("row");
    row = row.value;
    var col = document.getElementById("col");
    col = col.value;

    var insert = row + "_" + col;
    insert = insert.toString();
     var col = document.getElementById("col");
```

EDIT::     return column.value = v;
    } //end function

When I'm attempting to take the insert variable and use it as the id value, it breaks the whole program. Should I be casting the insert var to something other then a string?

Comment: `insert` is already a string, so there is probably no point of calling `insert.toString()`.

Comment: Should that be `var column = document.getElementById(insert)`? And what do you mean by "breaks the whole program"? Do you get an error message? Or does it do something unexpected?

Comment: Fixed, the break issue, it's simply was breaking the javascript file saying that it couldn't call the create table function. A issue resulting from incorrect syntax

Answer (score 0):

I assume

```
var column.getElementById(insert);
```

should be

```
var column = document.getElementById(insert);
```

Your line of code is invalid.

Comment: Thanks! I have a bad tendency to miss simple things like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertValue() {
    var v = document.getElementById("submitText");
    v = v.value;
    var row = document.getElementById("row");
    row = row.value;
    var col = document.getElementById("col");
    col = col.value;

    var insert = row + "_" + col;
    // Don't really think this is necessary, so probably remove it.
    //insert = insert.toString();
    var column = document.getElementById(insert); // Compare this line to yours

    column.value = v;
} //end function
```

The reason of having error is because you're not writing it correctly.
`var column.getElementById(insert);` is **wrong syntax**. `var` is supposed to be followed by a variable name, and you can assign an initial value to it.

It is surprising that though you got it correct in the beginning but fail to do so later.

But the next time you have an error in your JavaScript code, check the browser's JavaScript Console. It can probably be opened using <kbd>F12</kbd>, and inside you will see the error is shown. Then you will not need to always come up and ask a question for every single problem you met. :)